# AsyncTask must be abstract

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty new to AsyncTask on Android, I'm trying to pass an int with

```
new startTestAsync().execute(grayVal);
```

to this AsyncTask

```
public class startTestAsync extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
double[] timeArray = new double[500]; // set array
double lagStartTime;
double lagEndTime;
double lagTimeResult;
int testAmount;

protected void doInBackground(int...grayVal) {
    for (testAmount = 0; testAmount < 500; testAmount++) {
        lagStartTime = System.nanoTime(); //start lagTimer start
        while (grayVal >= 100) {
            Log.i("Mat Value", String.valueOf(grayVal));
            lagEndTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
    }
 }
```

Android studio says that "AsyncTask must be abstract", I have no idea how to fix this as I am new to AsyncTasks.

edit: full code http://pastebin.com/vrf8Rb3h

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> AsyncTask must be subclassed to be used. The subclass will override at
>   least one method (doInBackground(Params...)), and most often will
>   override a second one (onPostExecute(Result).)

That means, you have to override the method onPostExecute(Result) too:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) { 
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing it like this:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... grayVal)
    {
        for (testAmount = 0; testAmount < 500; testAmount++)
        {
            lagStartTime = System.nanoTime();
            while (grayVal[0] >= 100)   // you need to loop over grayVal properly if you are sending multiple values(it's just an example), if there is just one value you can write grayVal[0].
            {
                Log.i("Mat Value", String.valueOf(grayVal.intValue()));
                lagEndTime = System.nanoTime();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

you set the parameters of `doInBackground` to `int`, it should be an `Integer` and the return is a `Void` rather than a `void` so you should explicitly return `null`.

Comment: I made your changes, but now I'm getting  Mat Value﹕ [Ljava.lang.Integer;@3a2f7f9c in logcat instead of that value that is in grayVal.

Comment: @Nbun its advisable to use "@override" annotations when your are extending a class. So please annotations before doInBackground() and other methods which you are overriding from AsyncTask

Comment: my problem is every time I put new startTestAsync(grayVal).execute(); I get a syntax error, but if I put new startTestAsync().execute(grayVal); I don't. when I put new startTestAsync().execute(grayVal); I don't get the value of grayVal.

Comment: you will be able to get the value of grayVal like this: grayVal[0], check the current code and let me know if the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameters to  `AsyncTask` with two approach. 
these are:
1-make parameterized constructor.means
You can override the constructor. Something like:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

public MyAsyncTask(int showLoading) {
    super();
    // do stuff
}

// doInBackground() et al.
}
```

and call this `AsynTask` like

```
MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
task.showLoading = 12;
task.execute();
```

2-pass values in `execute()` statement.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<MyClass, Void, Boolean> {

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(MyClass... params) {

    // Do blah blah with param1 and param2
    MyClass myClass = params[0];

    String param1 = myClass.getParam1();
    String param2 = myClass.getParam2();

    return null;
}
}
```

and call it like

```
AsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask().execute(new MyClass());
```

enjoy your code:)